# How to retrieve detailed error message?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://nonexistingdomainblabla.net',
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
    ...
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, ex)
    {
        console.log('failed to get subscription list: ' + JSON.stringify(jqxhr));
    });
```

This returns

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

without any status code or response text. I would like to get more detailed error message while keeping my ajax request as much intact as possible.

Comment: There's a few cases where a status code of `0` can be retrieved. For example, if the data sent/received is not in a valid format, or if the page is redirected while the request is processing, so `abort()` is called. We need to see more of your code to help you.

Comment: I am using jQuery mobile and ajax call is wrapped into `$('#splashPage').on('pageshow',function(event) {...}`.

Comment: What you are seeing is what was returned from the service. You can confirm this (or not) by looking at the Network tab of your browser's developer tools and looking at the full response.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: not network tab, but console tab tells me `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. I would expect to be able retrieve more or less same error from my request and not just "error".

Comment: Well, you can expect all you want :). That's just not what the XMLHttpRequest functionality in your browser is providing. That particular error occurs before the request is even sent; it means the DNS can't find the hostname of your URL.

Comment: So it appears some errors are handled solely by browser and not bubbled up to xhr...

Answer (score -1):

try using error function:

```
error: function(jqxhr, status, error) {
  var err = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
  console.log('failed to get subscription list: ' + err);
}
```

Comment: could you confirm status code with console.log(jqxhr.status) ?

Comment: `jqxhr.status` is 0